# data.table - group by with custom functions that returns a matrix

Tags: r, data.table

I have below `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT = as.data.table(data.frame(Z=c("abc","abc","def","abc"), column=c(1,2,3,4), someOtherColumn=c(5,6,7,8)))

Fn = function(DT1) {
        Value = as.numeric(DT1[1, 2])
        Calc = sapply(DT1[, c("Z"):=NULL], sum) - Value
        return(matrix(Calc, nr = 1, nc = length(Calc)))
    }
```

Now, I want to apply `Fn()` to each group formed by `'Z'`, and get a resulting matrix with 2 rows (because there are 2 unique members in `DT$Z`) and 2 rows

```
DT[, Fn(.SD), by = Z, .SDcols = c('Z', 'column', 'someOtherColumn')]
```

But with that I am getting error as

```
Error in `[.data.table`(DT1, , `:=`(c("Z"), NULL)) : 
  .SD is locked. Using := in .SD's j is reserved for possible future use; a tortuously flexible way to modify by group. Use := in j directly to modify by group by reference.
```

I could apply `lapply()` to achieve the same as below

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(DT, DT[['Z']]), Fn))
```

Any pointer towards the right approach to achieve that same will be helpful.

I have a quite big `DT, so am looking for some efficient method.`

Comment: Your function doesn't make any sense. So, you should explain what you are actually trying to achieve with it.

Comment: @Roland - what do you mean by function dont make any sense? Is there any inaccuracy in that function? that is certainly not. I have given a reproducible example that mostly should work as well as intended result. It is not necessary that OP needs to always give an example which ought to be meaningful to every readers

Comment: @Bogaso maybe you can explain how my answer can be improved to address the problem and make it run *efficiently*

Comment: A function to be used inside data.table shouldn't return a matrix. You should subset instead of setting a column to NULL (that's what causes the error, you are working with a reference here and not with a copy). You should use lapply inside a data.table not outside if you want efficiency. But you should explain what you want to achieve if you want an efficient solution. Your function is so badly written that it's more work to understand it than I'm willing to invest. Sorry.

Comment: @Roland - I have given an example function (generic) to demonstrate the issue, which I am looking for a solution. It may not be prudent to find meaning with that function. My actual function is proprietary in nature and therefore I do not want to publish that here. My Q is: How can I group a data.table based on a column and apply function with each group that returns vector and that function take inputs from multiple columns of same data.table. <1/2>

Comment: The examples which I have come across so far, generally apply function for which input is a single column and output is a single value (i.e. mean(v2)). But my case is -  input based on multiple columns and output is a vector. Let me know if further clarification required <2/2>

Comment: .SD is a data.table and thus also a data.frame and a list. Just write a function that accepts either of these data structures as input. The current answer demonstrates how to specify which columns go into .SD (it's also explained in the package vignettes). You just can't modify the input data.table inside the function without explicitly making a copy (which would hurt performance dramatically). Can't really help more without a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to fix the code to get it run - I am no `data.table` expert, so I can not give insight into its working. Maybe this is what you are after.

I don't think `Fn` can return a matrix since `'j'` has to be either a list or atomic vectors.

```
 Fn = function(DT1) {
  Value = as.numeric(DT1[1,  2])
  Calc = DT1[, lapply(.SD, sum) , .SDcols = -"Z"] - Value
  list(matrix(Calc, nrow = 1, ncol = length(Calc)))
}

out <- DT[, .(Fn(.SD)), by = Z, .SDcols = c("Z", "column", "someOtherColumn")]

> out
# Z       V1
# 1: abc <matrix>
# 2: def <matrix>

#  b$V1
# [[1]]
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,] 6    18  
# 
# [[2]]
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,] 0    4
```